# Activate UISearchController without animation on navigation push

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

In the `UISearchDisplayController` there was a way to set it active without animations in the `viewWillAppear:` method so the view controller will push with already activated `UISearchDisplayController` and already shown keyboard, which was pretty nice. But it is deprecated now.

Now we have `UISearchController` and I'm only able to do it with two animations: first is navigation push, then activation animation. I want to see only navigation push animation, and searchController already activated with searchbar as first responder and keyboard shown.

I tried

```
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation { () -> Void in
        self.searchController.active = true
    }
```

and tried to use custom empty presenting delegate method

```
func presentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

}
```

Comment: Did you figure anything out for this?

Comment: No, Ryan Poolos, I did not. I decided to use `UISearchDisplayController` until a good fix discover

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer but...

I was trying to dismiss a `UISearchController` by setting `.active` to `false` without the animation and your hint of `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` did the trick

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation { // disable the animation as we are going straight to another view
    searchController.isActive = false
}
```